Google Auth @react-native-google-signin/google-signin DEVELOPER_ERROR
I had google setup with expo-auth-session before that was working but suddenly it stopped was getting error 400. Following their suggestion I started setting with react-native-google-signin package. But I keep getting the error: [Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR] with no more context. Following the https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/setting-up/expo with firebase authentication.
imported the necessary files
My signIn component.
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  statusCodes,
  isErrorWithCode,
  isSuccessResponse
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Alert, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithCredential
} from '../../services/firebase'
import { mixpanel } from '../../utils'

import { setAuthState, setLoading } from '../../features/auth/auth'
import { IMGS } from '../../constants'
import { BtnWithIcon } from '../../components'

const GoogleSignIn = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const webClientId = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID
  const iosClientId = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_IOS_CLIENT_ID

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId,
      iosClientId
    })

    console.log('googleConfig GoogleSignIn:')
  }, [])

  const signIn = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth()

    try {
      const hasPlayServices = await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices()

      if (hasPlayServices) {
        const response = await GoogleSignin.signIn()
        console.log('response GoogleSignIn:', response)

        if (isSuccessResponse(response)) {
          console.log('response GoogleSignIn:', response)
          // await signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
        } else {
          console.log('response GoogleSignIn cancelled:', response)
          // sign in was cancelled by user
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (isErrorWithCode(error)) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS:
            console.log('Sign in already in progress')
            break
          case statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            console.log('Play services not available or outdated')
            break
          default:
            console.log('Some other error happened:', error)
        }
      } else {
        console.log('error GoogleSignIn:', error)
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <BtnWithIcon
        action={async () => {
          console.log('action GoogleSignIn')
          dispatch(setLoading(true))
          try {
            await signIn()
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during authentication:', error)
          }
        }}
        icon={IMGS.googleIcon}
        label="Continue with Google"
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default GoogleSignIn

